# how can i set pip3 install path in ubuntu

Tags: pip, ubuntu-18.04

I'm installing software on Ubuntu 18.04, and used command:

```
pip3 install -U --user --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed foo.whl \
    -i https://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple --trusted-host mirrors.aliyun.com
```

and I found that it was installed at "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages", not under "~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages". So I wonder how can i adjust the installation path

Comment: The reason I ask this question is that I have another software that depends on this foo.whl, but it shows "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement" error

Comment: Update: I found that foo.whl was installed under `/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`, and fooB that depends on it was installed under `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages`, probably this is why it cannot find it. But the problem is that my install commands are the same:  `pip3 install -U --user --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed ${foo_whl}  -i 
 https://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple --trusted-host mirrors.aliyun.com`  How does it control where it installs at?